# MongoDb query not returning all the fields

Tags: mongodb

Why following statement is not returning me all the fields from collection in mongoDb

```
db.post.find({"ppu":0.55}, {$or : [{"name":"Cake"}, {"name":"Raised"}]})
```

This is returning me just an objectId column _id not all the fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [syntax of find](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) is:

```
db.collection.find(<criteria>, <projection>)
```

So your second parameter should be a projection, but it's not. What the projection looks like is explained very well in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

```
db.post.find({"ppu":0.55}, {$or : [{"name":"Cake"}, {"name":"Raised"}]})
                        ^
```

Change your query to the following because the second argument to the find method should be a **projection** which it is not in your case

```
db.post.find({"ppu":0.55, $or : [{"name":"Cake"}, {"name":"Raised"}]})
```